# Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type [Tracker.Models.INV_Assets]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, ienumerable

I'm putting together a fairly simple Code-First MVC5 Inventory Tracking application. I've gotten my app to Seed() and all of my Maintenance tables (Locations, Vendors, Statuses, etc.) I can view/create/edit/delete. I'm now working on the `View` for my main [INV_Assets] model, but when trying to `foreach` through the items in my model to display all [INV_Assets] in a table, I get the error: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Tracker.Models.INV_Assets' because 'Tracker.Models.INV_Assets' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`.

Below is the Model for my `[INV_Assets]`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using GridMvc.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Tracker.Models;

namespace Tracker.Models
{
    [GridTable(PagingEnabled = true, PageSize = 30)]
    public class INV_Assets 
    {
        // Setting GridColumn Annotations allows you to use AutoGenerateColumns on view to auto create the Grid based on the model.


        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }

        // Flag to specify if item is available? (Not signed out, not auctioned, recycled, etc.)
        //public bool available { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**[INV_Assets] View**:

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@model  Tracker.Models.INV_Assets

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<table style="width:100%;">

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.owner)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vendor)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asset_tag_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.serial_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ip_address)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mac_address)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.po_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.invoice_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cost)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.note)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.acquired_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.disposed_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_by)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modified_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modified_by)</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I'm not quite sure how to get around this error and wondered if someone with more experience could weigh-in?

I am getting no issue (not sure why) from my `[INV_Locations]` Model/View when doing the same:

**[INV_Locations]**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Tracker.Models
{
    public class INV_Locations
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string location_dept { get; set; }
        public string location_room { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**[INV_Locations] View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tracker.Models.INV_Locations>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Maintenance - Locations</h3>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.location_dept)*@
            Dept:
        </th>
        <th>
            Room:
        </th>
        <th>
            Created:
        </th>
        <th>
            By:
        </th>
        <th>
            Modified:
        </th>
        <th>
            By:
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.location_dept)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.location_room)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_by)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modified_date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modified_by)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I tried changing `@model  Tracker.Models.INV_Assets` to `@model  IEnumerable<Tracker.Models.INV_Assets>` on my [INV_Assets] `View` (just like how my [INV_Locations] `View` has it. This allows my solution to Build, but when trying to run my application to that `View` I receive: 
`System.InvalidOperationException
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Tracker.Models.INV_Assets', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[Tracker.Models.INV_Assets]'.`

---

**EDIT - Regarding Shyju's Suggestion**:

I changed my `HomeController` `Index()` from:

```
    TrackerContext _db = new TrackerContext();
    public ActionResult Index(INV_Assets defModel)
    {
        return View(defModel);
    }
```

to:

```
    TrackerContext _db = new TrackerContext();
    public ActionResult Index(INV_Assets defModel)
    {
        var assetList = new List<Tracker.Models.INV_Assets>();

        assetList.Add(defModel);
        return View(assetList);
    }
```

While my View now loads, all I get for the Table HTML is:

```
<table style="width:100%;">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>01/01/0001</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>01/01/0001</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I've confirmed that my DBContext has 2 complete [INV_Assets] records in it, but they are not showing up in the View? How do I correctly load all the instances of my [INV_Assets] model into the new `assetList` variable?

---

**EDIT2**:

Modified my `Index()` to:

```
    TrackerContext _db = new TrackerContext();
    public ActionResult Index(INV_Assets defModel)
    {
        var assetList = _db.INV_Assets.ToList(); // EXCEPTION
        return View(assetList);
    }
```

but now, while the solution builds, the application fails when I try to run it. Details below:

**Error**: `An exception of type 'System.Data.DataException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.`

**Message**: `An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.`

**InnerException**: `{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}`

**Source**: `EntityFramework`

Answer (score 1):

Your view is bound to a single instance of `Tracker.Models.INV_Assets`. But inside your view, you are trying to loop through it. You need to make sure what was passed to your view is a collection, so that we can loop through it.

In INV Assets view, change

`@model  Tracker.Models.INV_Assets`

to

```
@model  List<Tracker.Models.INV_Assets>
```

Also you need to make sure that you are passing a collection of `INV_Assets` objects from your action method.

```
public ActionResult INVAssets()
{
  var assetList=new List<Tracker.Models.INV_Assets>();

  // Ex : manually adding one record. replace with your actual code to load data
  // to do : Add item to the list now
  assetList.Add(new INV_Assets { Name ="Test"});

  return View(assetList);     
}
```

**Edit :** *As per the edit in the question*

Your `Index` action should not be taking an object of `INV_Assets` as parameter.

```
TrackerContext _db = new TrackerContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var assetList =_db.INV_Assets.ToList();     
    return View(assetList);
}
```

Asssuming `INV_Assets` is a property on your `TrackerContext` class. If your property name is different, change the above code to reflect that.

If you want to load load the assets for a specific location, update your Index action method to accept the location id as a parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var assetList =_db.INV_Assets.Where(s=>s.Location_Id==id).ToList();     
    return View(assetList);
}
```

So your url to access this page would be like

```
http://yoursitename/YourControllerName/Index/5
```

where `5` is a valid location id which has some assets associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for replying Shyju. When I make your suggested change from `IEnumerable<>` to `List` (after adding in a `using System.Collections.Generic`) my error now changes over to (similar): `System.InvalidOperationException
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Tracker.Models.INV_Assets', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[Tracker.Models.INV_Assets]'.`

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to figure out how to load all of my Model instances into the new assetList variable?

Comment: Still not having any luck. I added an Edit above to show where I'm at.

Comment: I've made an EDIT2 above for a new Exception that is occurring with the latest change using your `ToList()` example.